# Stack Smashing Detected upon input fgets

Tags: c, arrays, string, function, fgets

The purpose is to enter string1 and string2 and remove any occurrence of any of the letters in string2 from string1. I get a stack smashing detection error after I input my second string. The function rmchr works fine. It's once we get to rmstr.

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "rmstr.h"

int main()
{
  int ch, l;
  char x[3];
  x[0]='y';

  while(x[0]=='y'||x[0]=='Y')
  {
    char string[100]={0}, string1[100]={0}, string2[100]={0}, c[3];

    printf("Enter a String: ");
    fgets(string, 100, stdin);
    if (string[98] == '\n' && string[99] == '\0') { while ( (ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && ch != '\n'); }

    printf("Enter a Char: ");
    fgets(c, 2, stdin);
    while ( (ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && ch != '\n');

    rmchr(string, c[0]);

    printf("Enter a String: ");
    fgets(string1, 100, stdin);
    if (string1[98] == '\n' && string1[99] == '\0') { while ( (ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && ch != '\n'); }


    printf("Enter the second string: ");
    fgets(string2, 100, stdin);
    if (string2[98] == '\n' && string2[99] == '\0') { while ( (ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && ch != '\n'); }

    rmstr(string1, string2);

    printf("Run Again?(y/n):");
    fgets(x, 2, stdin);
    while ( (ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && ch != '\n');
  }

 return 0;
}
```

functions.h:

```
rmchr(char *string, char c)
{ 
  int i=0, j=0, count=0;
  char word[100]={0};

  int s = strlen(string);

  for(i=0; i<=(s-2); i++)
  {
    if(string[i] != c && string[i] != ' ')
    {
      word[count] = string[i];
      count++;
    }    
  }

  printf("Word: ");
  for(i=0; i<=count; i++)
  {
    printf("%c", word[i]); 
  }
  printf("\n"); 
}

rmstr(char *string1, char *string2)
{
   int i=0, j=0, count=0;
   char word[100]={0};

   int s = strlen(string1);
   int l = strlen(string2);

   for(i=0; i<=(s-2); i++)
   {
    for(j=0; j<=(s-2); j++)
    {
      if(string1[i] != string2[j] && string1[i] != ' ')
      {
        word[count] = string1[i];
        count++;
      }

    }

  }
}
```

sample outpput:

```
Enter a String: Ahhaha
Enter a Char: h
Word: Aaa
Enter a String: Annabcdcbcdbckje
Enter the second string: n
*** stack smashing detected ***: ./q4 terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Your loops in `rmstr` are not constructed correctly. Step through it to see why. The inner loop causes the **same** character from `string1` to be **repeatedly** copied for every `string2` character that is not the same as the current `string1` character. Which will obviously make `count` become too large and overflow the `word` buffer.

Comment: I think you need to keep track of whether the same character has been found and then only do the copy **after** the inner loop has completed if a same character has not been matched.

Answer (score 0):

In `rmstr`:

```
  for(i=0; i<=(s-2); i++)    {
    for(j=0; j<=(s-2); j++)
    {
      if(string1[i] != string2[j] && string1[i] != ' ')
      {
        word[count] = string1[i];
        count++;
      }

    }
```

You `count` value is always incremented in this loop of loop and can be bigger than the maximum allowed value of `99` (the last element of `word` array). For example if `s` is 12, then `s - 2` * `s - 2` will give `count` to `100`.

Moreover at first glance it seems you forgot to use `l` in the second loop using `s` instead.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to fix my loops?